# Trying to get property on a non object Yii 1.1.15

Tags: php, yii, warnings

I try to change Css file for CGridView widget, in my `config/main.php`:

```
'components' => array(
     'widgetFactory' => array(
         'widgets' => array(
            'CGridView' => array(
                'cssFile' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/css/gridview.css',
            ),
         ),
      ),
  ...
```

And I get warning:

```
Trying to get property on a non object /path_to_project/protected/config/main.php on line 79
```

How I can suppress this warning, and why I getting it, in when I using it in view files it all works.

P.S. Yes I can set `display_errors` ini set to false and message will dissapearm but I want get clearly with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the warning is that the [CHttpRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest) object `Yii::app()->request` has not been instantiated yet.

From [the API page for CApplication](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication):

> CApplication will undergo the following lifecycles when processing a
>   user request:
>
> 1. load application configuration;
> 2. set up error handling;
> 3. load static application components;
> 4. onBeginRequest: preprocess the user request;
> 5. processRequest: process the user request;
> 6. onEndRequest: postprocess the user request;
>
> Starting from lifecycle 3, if a PHP error or an uncaught exception occurs, the application will switch to its error handling logic and jump to step 6 afterwards.

Your error is happening at the first step. As such, Yii's error handling has not been setup yet. The only option is to suppress this warning using the [`@` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

```
 'cssFile' => @Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/css/gridview.css',
```

**HOWEVER**

This is a terrible idea, since you are essentially hiding the error instead of fixing it.

If your views are being displayed correctly (no css errors), you can omit the `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` and just use:

```
'cssFile' => '/css/gridview.css'
```

If you are experiencing errors, you can create a class in your `components` folder that extends `CWidgetFactory` and set any variables that depend on other components here e.g

```
class MyWidgetFactory extends CWidgetFactory {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->widgets['CGridView']['cssFile'] = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'css/gridview.css';
    }
}
```

You will need to adjust your `components` to use this file:

```
'components' => array(
    'widgetFactory' => array(
        'class' => 'MyWidgetFactory'
    ...
```